# Split columns in data frame in multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have created a data frame using the Dictionary , now I want to split 2 columns in data frame to 4 columns.

Initially there are 3 columns in data frame i.e Parent, Child and Score. I  want to Split "Parent" column to "col1 and col2" and "Child" column to "col3 and col4" and want to split it using delimeter '+'

I have tried some of the following methods can any one help

```
def request_service(Sentence,id):
        dict_ip = {"id": "2018 Regression", "Sentence": "What is the customers Issue/problem?  Customer spoke to our mobile banking help
        payload = json.dumps(dict_ip)
        print(payload)

        response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        dict_list = json.loads(response.text)
        print(dict_list)
        #dict_list = {'results': [{'Parent': 'A+B', 'child': 'C+D', 'score': 0.36283498590263946}, {'Parent': 'D+E', 'child': 'A+B', 'score': 0.10505374311256221}, {'Parent': 'N+M', 'child': 'Q+R', 'score': 0.09593593898873307}]}

        df_op = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Parent', 'Child', 'Score'])
        for idx, result in enumerate(dict_list['results']):
        df_op.loc[idx] = [result['Parent'], result['child'], result['score']]
        df_op.Score = df_op.Score.round(2)
        return df_op
```

Expected output is Datframe with 5 columns

```
 col1   col2   col3   col4   Score
  A      B      C      D      0.36
  D      E      A      B      0.10
  N      M      Q      R      0.09
```

Comment: Please rather add an example of the dataframe that you want to split (no need to show how it was obtained) and the expected output for _that particular dataframe_.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to SPLIT THE COLUMNS

```
df_op = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Parent', 'Child', 'Score'])
for idx, result in enumerate(dict_list['results']):
    df_op.loc[idx] = [result['Parent'], result['child'], result['score']]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df_op.Parent.str.split('+', expand=True).values,
         columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df_op.Child.str.split('+', expand=True).values,
                   columns=['col3', 'col4'])
df_op_mergerd = pd.concat([df3, df4, df_op], axis=1)
df_op_mergerd.drop(['Parent','Child'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```